# A generic word to define the superset of companies, NGOs and faculties

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I need a word to define a set which includes companies, NGOs and faculties that sounds equally distant to those 3.

I am not a native English speaker so I might be wrong but "Corporation" sounds like it is favoring "companies" more, and "institution" evokes "faculties".

Is there a more natural generic term for those? What would you think about "foundation" or "establishment"?

**edit:** I was thinking what is common to those 3. They are all *bodies with members*. So how about calling them *bodies*? A bit too general, though. What about *associations*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest **group** or **entity**.

Comment: thank you. i will pick _entity_ as it is generic enough to cover all 3 but more specific than a group.

Comment: That's funny, I would have thought it the other way around. A *group* is a more specific *entity*. After all, I am an entity, and not a group. :)

Comment: right, but it evokes _legal entity_ and in that sense it is narrower and fits well. also in the context, which is a web platform with some social aspects, _group_ maybe confused by a _social group_. thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

How about *organization*?  Possibly close to NGO, but NGO is quite explicitly a limited subset.  "Organization" is certainly the term I would use as an American English speaker.

The fact that NGO even has the meaning it does (American equivalent is "non-profit organization") suggests that "organization" has more specific connotations outside the US than I'm used to, though.  If these make it unsuitable, the most generic alternate term I can think of is *concern*.

Comment: thank you. i think _organization_ suits well for 'company' and 'ngo' but i am not sure about calling 'faculty' an 'organization'. _concern_ may be technically the best choice but its primary meaning may cause confusion. still, i may go with _organization_.

Comment: The acronym "NGO" is not of American vintage? Really...huh.

Comment: @Billare: Nope, it's a bit mysterious to us.  To an American who hasn't done business internationally, the term "non-governmental organization" seems to very handily encompass for-profit corporations and partnerships.  It's an organization and it's not part of the government, and all.