# A superset of contractor, employee and businesses?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, hypernyms

I need a single word to define an employee, contractor or any business entity (e.g. sole-proprietorship, corporation) that provides services in exchange for pay.

I saw https://english.stackexchange.com/a/14187/152901 but the terminology is too vague for my liking.

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/248668/152901 suggests "Vendor" which comes close to what I'm looking for, but I don't believe the definition covers employees.

**UPDATE**: I am looking for a word which is the union of a "Vendor" (which refers to a company) and "Worker" (which refers to an individual). Ideally the word should be stated from the perspective of the individual/company (what would they call themselves?) and should imply some sort of business relationship.

Comment: It's hyphenated, but how about: "service-provider"?

Comment: @Nonnal I thought of the same, but I'm looking for a non-hyphenated single word :)

Comment: Then just "Provider"

Comment: @Jim "Provider" implies only one end of the relationship. Yes, someone is providing services but the word does not imply that the individual/company is getting paid for the service. I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: Why are you mixing workers and companies here? All employees work for a company so you could always put a company name there (for sole- proprietors you can put the person’s name as the company name) OR the other way is to always put the employee’s name regardless of which company they work for- it that’s what’s important.  If it’s a matter of your own eemployees names or subcontracting the work out, then you can out your own company name when work is being performed by your employees.

Comment: Also shouldn’t context make it clear what kind of provider it is and that they are getting paid for it?

Comment: @Jim Unfortunately not. I am using this word in a programming context (as part of a class name). In such a context, the word `Provider` has many different meanings. Why do I want a single word for both individuals and a company? Because I am programming a tax simulator where the individual filing taxes might be working as an Employee or Contractor for a Sole-Proprietorship, Corporation, etc. The different "worker" types have common functionalities so I need a name for the base class.

Comment: What does your employer (or client, as the case may be) call them?

Comment: Who says Vendor refers to only companies? It can mean both companies and individuals. The ice-cream truck owner who has set shop adjacent to the market road would be an individual vendor. Baskin&Robbins would be a multi-national vendor. I'd go with vendor. More like `public class Vendor`! ;)

Comment: Wouldn’t that then be ***taxpayer***?

Comment: If this is for a class name just invent a term, such as *vendployee*.  You and your coworkers are the only ones who will care.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Yes, but can a "Vendor" refer to an Employee? :)

Comment: Why do people spend so much time searching for The Perfect Class Name? You could call the class Lemonade and it'd work just as well.

Comment: @Marthaª I've asked myself the same question. I can't believe the amount of time I've wasted over the years hunting for the correct class name, yet the perfectionist in me refuses to let it go ;)

Comment: I am not finding much in WordNet. Looks like WordNet's definitions (and hypernym allocations) for bussinessy things are weak. http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/oxinabox/774f794cefd76878bfc9f89d08ad96b8

Comment: It looks as if you are really asking "Please name this class in my program", and since we know no spaces are allowed, you want one word. But how about using camelCase for something like "servProv"? No spaces, short, perhaps even memorable.

Comment: @frank The one word limitation doesn't come from the inability to use spaces. It comes from the fact that there will be many subclasses of this type. If the superclass name is longer than one word, subclass names will end up too long.

Comment: I solved a problem like that in a team environment by calling the superclass **fred**. Soon the whole team was talking about fred as if he was a team member, as in "fred can write the 8080 interpreter in no time". The pointy-headed manager didn't know why they laughed when he asked "Fred Who?"

Answer (score 1):

Since employees and independent contractors are handled differently in taxation in the U. S., one receiving a W2 and the other self-employeed, one usually having taxes withheld by their employer and the other having to pay self-employment tax (Social Security) in addition to income tax, etc., there is no single word I know of that would accurately combine the two, let alone include other vendors like small businesses and corporations as well. **@Jim** suggested the reasonable superset term, **"Taxpayers,"** which implies the one thing the components have in common with regards to a tax simulation program. My wife, a retired accountant with more than 35 years of experience in corporate, partnership and individual tax preparation, could not think of a better word that would include all the **entities** that will need to use your program.

**Edit 1-3-16:** @Gili, After thinking more about this for a few days, I came up with one other possibility that might work for you: **"Client."**

Comment: "Taxpayer" is not so bad (I'm still mulling it over) but I don't think it makes sense to refer to a Corporation as an "Employee" because it's not an employee of the customer company it is providing services to.

Comment: Point taken, and agreed. "Employee" would not describe a corporation. I'll edit it out of my answer. Best of luck finding just the right word!

Comment: I am actually looking for the opposite of "Client". Both "Vendor" and "Worker" have a "Client" but I am looking for a word to replace the former, not the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Such entities usually fall under the general category of *[consultant](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/consultant)*.