# Why isn't there a word for the super-type of people and businesses?

Tags: meaning, etymology, loanwords, collective-nouns

I was originally framing this question as a search for the 'right word' but the site's suggestions pointed me to a [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296248/a-superset-of-contractor-employee-and-businesses) that was almost identical. So I'll turn the question around and ask, *why* there isn't a word that describes the superset of People and Institutions ? Does anyone know of a word in another language that fits the bill? Care to coin a word for it?

**Meaning**

In the sense that both people and businesses have some traits in common: they all have addresses and phone numbers, it makes sense to 'have spoken to them', they both post stuff on the Internet, you can send an invoice to them etc., they are 'of a kind'. There is even a [legal concept](http://www.lawteacher.net/free-law-essays/business-law/separate-legal-personality-of-a-company-business-law-essay.php) of companies being persons.

'Entity' is too broad. Everything is an entity, even counting numbers. 'Institution' doesn't include individuals.

* As I haven't had many suggestions, I'm adding my own clumsy attempt to coin a word.
**Homosim**. Companies and people are homosimilar.
Also, I've discovered 'Party' works reasonably well.

Comment: Ah, but (in the US) a business is, as you state, a "person", so the "super-type" is "people".

Comment: mmm, OK. Now you owe me a single word for 'Genus homo' that sounds polite when it's applied to your Grandma :-)

Comment: @HotLicks Indeed the US supreme court is often quoted as saying that [corporations are people](https://www.google.com/search?q=corporations+are+people&oq=corporations+are+people&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). Whenever I hear that it makes me think of [soylent green](https://www.google.com/search?q=soylent+green&oq=soylent+green&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: It makes *me* think of HAL-9000 from 2001. "I'm sorry, Dave. I have to downsize..."

Comment: @CandiedOrange The US Supreme Court is never quoted accurately as saying "Corporations are people."  SCOTUS has said that the 14th Amendment guarantee of equal protection applies to corporations, but that's different.  Even the legalized bribery of *Citizens United* is not based on corporate personhood. The quote belongs to Mitt Romney, and although he was widely mocked for it, he was talking about S-corps, LLCs, and other so-called personal corporations that really are just individuals taking advantage of limitations on liability available to such legal fictions.

Comment: @deadrat - But the word "corporation" means, literally, "body", and the concept originates, oddly, with Thomas Jefferson, who proposed to the Virginia legislature that "corporations" should be allowed to function as if they were people.

Comment: @HotLicks The etymological fallacy?  Really?  There's a lot of nonsense on the internet about the words of the founders of the USA, so I'd like to see some provenance for Jefferson's argument that corporations should be allowed to function as people.  It would seem to be somewhat at odds with the man's view of the virtues of the agrarian society, but maybe you're right.  In any case, corporations do not function as if they were people -- they can't vote, for instance -- and the Supreme Court has not said that they do.

Comment: I can't readily find a reference for Jefferson's contribution, but [In Louisville, C. & C.R. Co. v. Letson, 2 How. 497, 558, 11 L.Ed. 353 (1844), the U.S. Supreme Court held that for the purposes of the case at hand, a corporation is "capable of being treated as a citizen of (the State which created it), as much as a natural person."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_personality).

Comment: @HotLicks the plural of *person* is *persons*, not *people*. We use *people* as if it were a plural , but it's really a mass noun, from the latin *populus* meaning the lower stratum of the populace. It has its own plural, *peoples*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ask for a super-type of two items, be they people, concepts or something else, you imply the existence of a [taxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy_%28general%29) that includes both as well as an item that is an ancestor to both.

We can therefore recast the question as "What is an appropriate taxonomy for people and businesses?"

First, what is a taxonomy?

> Taxonomy (from Greek taxis meaning arrangement or division and nomos meaning law) is the science of classification according to a pre-determined system, with the resulting catalog used to provide a conceptual framework for discussion, analysis, or information retrieval.
>   [- Margaret Rouse](http://searchcontentmanagement.techtarget.com/definition/taxonomy)

There isn't really a widely-used taxonomy that includes both people and businesses, so it's natural to ask how one might set up such a taxonomy.

> Two of the predominant types of relationships in knowledge-representation systems are predication and the universally quantified conditional. Predication relationships express the notion that an individual entity is an example of a certain type (for example, John is a bachelor), while universally quantified conditionals express the notion that a type is a subtype of another type (for example, A dog is a mammal, which means the same as All dogs are mammals).
>   [- Brachman, quoted by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy_%28general%29#Is-a_and_has-a_relationships)

(Although you use the term *super-type*, I take it that you would be happy for either style to produce a common word.)

We're now looking for commonalities, be it something that both are examples of, or a conceptual union of the concepts *people* and *businesses*.  The problem is that the concepts are arguably more different than [chalk and cheese](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/chalk-and-cheese.html) - one is real and the other is a legal fiction. You need to go a long way up the taxonomic tree to get to a common ancestor, at which point *entity* starts looking reasonable. Your objection that it is "too broad" simply reflects the distance between people and businesses in any generic taxonomy. That is, they are [ontologically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29) rather distinct.

Taking one more step into this rabbit warren, let's consider the [kind of ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29#Types) we can construct for your question. There are two basic types:

- *domain* ontology, which has a restricted universe of discussion (the domain); and
- *upper* ontology, which "describes very general concepts that are the same across all knowledge domains" [- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_ontology)

A *domain ontology*, say restricted to taxation, gives rise to 'super-types' such as *taxpayer*, and it seems to me that an *upper ontology* gives rise to 'super-types' such as *entity*.

**So the 'simple' answer to your question is that there *are* super-types for people and businesses. A deeper answer would likely need to delve into the fundamental nature of people and businesses.** I've started to look at that, but further exploration of this topic is perhaps best left for another question, given the length of this answer as it stands.

Comment: First ... **LOUD APPLAUSE !!**. You've nailed it. The reason there isn't such a word is probably because we still like to preserve something 'special' for real people, our amygdala won't handle combining squishy people with legal entities. I'll still cry foul over 'Entity'. I don't think you can find anything that falls outside the scope of 'entity'. ... mmm maybe another question in that....

Answer (score 3):

Consider **legal entity** (or legal person) that is a person or organization that can enter into contracts, and take part in legal action.

> A lawful or legally standing association, corporation, partnership,
>   proprietorship, trust, or individual, that has legal capacity to enter
>   into agreements or contracts, assume obligations, incur and pay debts,
>   sue and be sued in its own right, and to be accountable for illegal
>   activities.

Comment: That's right, but it doesn't really capture what I mean; speaking to, engaging with on the same level, doing 'human' things, getting the plumbing fixed. They are all things that even your dog can't do. I spoke to Telstra today, and I spoke to my mum. Not just the legal definitions.

Answer (score 0):

These categories are specific to the context, but include both individuals and businesses:

- Taxpayer - not all, but most, fall into this category (tongue-in-cheek).
- Account (or account-holder)- in the context of another business.

Comment: I don't mind 'account' , it would work in a financial context, though it's probably a bit ambiguous. 'The account has an outstanding account'. Is it his financials or his child that we're referring to?